# UIView causes UITableView children to be locked up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a subclass of UITableView that works just fine in one view, but when I try to use it in another view it will load with cells just fine and display them, but it doesn't respond to user input. Does anyone here have any idea as to what might be causing such paralysis?

I would also add that telling the table view to become first responder does nothing, and that it is already set to accept user interaction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

either the containing view has user interaction disabled, or there is a transparent view on top intercepting touches.

Comment: If there is such a view on top, it's only covering the rectangular area of the UITableView. No other control is affected, including a scroll view.